# No such slot QProgressBar::setValue(const int)

Tags: c++, qt

I have this line in my code:

```
    QObject::connect(scanning_worker, SIGNAL(update_progress_bar(const int)), ui.progress_bar, SLOT(setValue(const int)));
```

and in runtime I get this error:

```
    No such slot QProgressBar::setValue(const int)
```

any ideas why?
In documentation QT 4.8 (which I use) is that `setValue` is `public slot`...

I tried this: I deleted `const` before `int` in argument, but no changes. I tried to call other slot with debugger and my breakpoint in this slot was found, so it was ok. I also tried to set '50' as argument of setValue

```
    QObject::connect(scanning_worker, SIGNAL(update_progress_bar(const int)), ui.progress_bar, SLOT(setValue(50)));
```

but still the same error...

My class:

```
    class Scanning_worker : public QObject{
        Q_OBJECT
    private:
        int shots_count;
    public:
        Scanning_worker(const int shots) : shots_count(shots){}
        ~Scanning_worker(){}
    public slots:
        void do_work();
    signals:
        void error(const int err_num);
        void update_progress_bar(int value);
        void finished();
    };
```

And ui.progress_bar is in form (child of mainwindow)...

I work in visual studio 2010, W7 prof and QT 4.8

Comment: "I deleted const before int in argument" - you mean, in the SLOT(...)?

Comment: no...SLOT(update_progress_bar(int))...

Comment: it should be: `QObject::connect(scanning_worker, SIGNAL(update_progress_bar(int)), ui.progress_bar, SLOT(setValue(int)));`. No `const` at all.

Comment: no, I checked it...by the way, the compiler checks it

Comment: Marek R : my post bellow...no changes

Comment: no compiler doesn't check anything in connect. This is done at run time using meta data generated by moc program. Macro `SIGNAL(somthing)` changes argument to a c-string (with prefix which 0 or 1).

Comment: yes,in macro compiler doesnt check anything,but "ui.progress_bar" is checked by compiler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The slot wants an `int`: and you are giving it a `const int`, hence the error. Changing `SLOT(setValue(const int))` to `SLOT(setValue(int))` is not enough. You will need to change your signal, so it has an `int` argument, instead of `const int' too:

```
QObject::connect(scanning_worker, SIGNAL(update_progress_bar(int)), ui.progress_bar, SLOT(setValue(int)));
```

Basically, your signals should always have the exact same arguments as your slots, or it will not work. There is also another way to connect signals to slots which will give you compile-time errors if you do something wrong. Let's say you have a class like this:

```
class Foo : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void fooSlot(){ }
signals:
    void fooSignal(){ }
};
Foo *a = new Foo();
```

If you use qt5 then instead of connecting like this:

```
connect( a, SIGNAL(fooSignal()), a, SLOT(fooSlot()) );
```

you can also connect like this:

```
connect(  a, &Foo::fooSignal, a, &Foo::fooSlot );
```

In this case, if you make an error, it will show up during the compilation. It also has less parenthesis, so it's easier to read :P

Comment: sure its included in my sentence,if I deleted "const" in SLOT, I deleted it in SIGNAL too... no changes

Comment: @Jana, have you also changed the signal's signature in your class, and checked the argument that you `emit`?

Comment: and yes,i checked everything

Comment: @Jana, ok, could you please add the part of your class where your signal is defined, and the lines where it is emitted to the question? Also, you can't pass a value in the `connect` like this: `SLOT(setValue(50))`, slots do not work this way. _edit:_ I'm going home from work now, so I'll take a look at the question again in about an hour.

Comment: @ SingerOfTheFall i edited my Question with my class =/ ok, thanks so far

Comment: @ SingerOfTheFall now, there is no errors, but no SLOT invoked =/ only other slot, no progress bar =(

Comment: @Jana, is the value that you are sending into the slot within the progress bar's minimum-maximum range? Also, does the value change properly if you just call `setValue()` manually?

Comment: @ SingerOfTheFall - yeees you got it...my fault was, that I set the range 0-200, BUT I recounted the value for  range 0-100 (I missed it)...So it doesnt work,because I didnt set whole range...THANKS!